# How to intercept the request/response in WCF

Tags: asp.net

I creaed the sample service in wcf and also successfully used the web service in the sample application. Now I just want to log the request/response to/from the WCF service.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built in tracing functionality in WCF that can be used to log the requests and responses. The logs are viewed with the [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx). On that page there is also a description on how to configure your service for logging.

If you need to hook up your own code to execute when a call is made, you can do that through ServiceBehaviours and the [`IServiceBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.applydispatchbehavior.aspx) method. The latter is a quite advanced method though, so I only recommend it if you have found out that you need more that the built in tracing can give.

Comment: Thank you very much... the log file is availabe but when i double-click the file, the viewer says there is no trace file.I can view the file in notpad